# base64 format image making a server request

Tags: html, css, asp.net, web

i convert an image  to base64 format

and i changed

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl="Images/Icon.png"
```

to

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl="data:base64;
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACoAAAAoCAYAAACIC2hQAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAA......."
```

When i ran the application and opened network tab, i filtered using image requests, i saw that base 64 image also got captured.

[image]

So does it means that this is making a server hit?

Comment: why not simply open up the console and have a look at the browser tab? or use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: @vingesh and if you click that line, what information regarding the actual http-request does it give you? any hint that it hits the server (via IP or name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base64 encoded image will not hit the server. What the base64 is is literally the image data represented in base64 format. It'll just add onto the file size of wherever your CSS styling is (whether in a stylesheet or inline).